# Squat Replacement While Rehabing Ankle

Tags: weightlifting, injury

I sprained my ankle a while back and my ankle feels good, so I attempted to squat. Air squats were fine, but when I added the bar and 25lbs, my ankle started to feel unstable. I decided to stop squatting until it feels better.

Now, my program's lower body day (Candito's Linear) says Back Squat, Deadlift and  2 Accessories. As for my accessories, I do  Leg Press and Hamstring Curls.

What's a good substitute for Squats while I get the stability in my ankle? I'm working on the strength of my ankle, so I need a temporary substitute.

Update:
I go to a gym that has a decent amount of stuff. Leg Press, balance boards, leg raise machine, elastic bands, calf raise machine, hamstring curl machine. That's about all I can think of. I do Deadlifts, but that doesn't bother me unlike the squat.

Comment: What equipment, if any, do you have available.  Please edit with more info.

Comment: Added list of equipment, is there anything else that I could have not considered? (It may have more, I'm not sure)

Comment: Ankle stability may not just be a matter of strength after a sprain.  If you have finished physical therapy, you may want to add the exercises linked to on this proprioception q/a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think leg press and Romanian deadlift for compound movements that focus on quads and hamstrings respectively. Finish with some leg extensions and leg curls.  Don't do any of these if they aggravate your injury.

Comment: I did end up doing these while working on getting my squats back. Just doing squats got my ankle stable enough and I slowly started adding weight back up. I'm about 3/4 of the way back to where I was, taking it slowly, adding weight to my squats until I found it challenging to keep my balance. Leg Press and Dead Lifts (I did not do RDL) worked fine in the mean time.